# Diff-In-Diff with no aggregation group with cross-sectional data

Tags: econometrics, difference-in-difference

I was wondering whether there are papers covering the possibility of conducting a DiD analysis with no aggregation group.

I am tryng to highlight the impact of a reform on a set of health outcomes, my data come from a US health survey. I divided the individuals into treated and controls but I so not have any aggregation level for the units, i.e. I do not have, say, state, thanks to which I could have the traditional 2x2 setup:

I have a pre and a post-treatment period but no aggregation group as, again, state that helps divide the units into treated/control individuals living in a treated/control state.

Comment: Welcome. Well, technically you do have a treatment group. The group doesn’t have to be some large areal unit, though it often is. Can you tell me more about what distinguishes the treatment and control group in your setting? What is your treatment? In short, the treatment can be at the individual level.

Comment: Sure @ThomasBilach. My treatment is actually at the inidividual level and it is the Obamacare (I know states have introduced it at different times but I do not have the state variable in my dataset so I cannot exploit it in my analysis). I want to study the impact of the medicaid expansion on a set of health outcomes, so I reconstructed the treatment dummy by coding the criteria for which an indiivdual benefitted from the reform or not.